# Why I can't find vendor/autoload.php for 000webHost

Tags: phpmyadmin, webserver, web-hosting, autoload, vendor

I am using **000webHost** as a server for my android application 
But now when I am opening the **000webHost phpmyadmin** from google chrome whindowx 10
it says the following

```
File ./vendor/autoload.php missing or not readable. 
Most likely you did not run Composer to install library files.
```

When everything is on sever then why I need to install library and If I do need to install then **from where and How?**

**Detailed solution will be appreciated**

Comment: What's with all the shouting.

Comment: Generaly when you deploy you application, you don't include file that are generate automaticaly by some build tools, labrary or package that you download because you will do that on you production server. In you case you must ensure composer is install on your production server (__00webHost__) and you will must run `composer install` command  will install all dependency that are specified in you `composer.json` file